# I am facing a difficulty with AWS Lambda function Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created the AWS lambda function and added the dependencies too but when I uploaded the jar and clicked on Test it is showing me this error

```
Error loading method JSONtoURL on class MinimumTool.Index: class 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

I have used maven with eclipse for creating the jar.
Here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>minimum-tool</groupId>
  <artifactId>lamda-pricing-tool</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>lamda-pricing-tool</name>
  <description>Minimum Pricing Tool</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20151123</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are declaring a dependency on `org.json:json` in pom.xml assuming that the relevant classes/jar will be available at runtime. That is typically the case when you are deploying your application in an environment where those classes are expected to be available. But if you are running this as a standalone application, the jar that the commands like `maven package` or `maven install` create do *not* contain them. So, you have to take an extra step to actually bundle those dependency classes into a jar, usually known as the **uber** jar.

Take a look at the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) and run your app with the jar it produces.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a zip file called the Deployment Package containing all your code, plus all the additional jar files your code uses.

Amazon has some documentation on doing this with Eclipse and Maven:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-and-eclipse.html

In particular,

- Right click on your `pom.xml` file, select Maven, Add Plugin.  Add group `org.apache.maven.plugins`, artifact `maven-shade-plugin`, version 2.3 or later.
- Right click on the project, select Run As, Maven build.  Edit the configuration and add `package shade:shade` into Goals.

Now when you build your project with Run, it will build a Deployment Package jar.